# Find MST on grid graph with only weight of 1 and 2 in $O(|V|+|E|)$

Tags: weighted-graphs, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

Given a grid graph $G=(V,E)$ which has only two different integer costs/weights of 1 and 2. Find Minimum Spanning Tree in $O(|V|+|E|)$.

I tried the following:

- Changing Kruskal using a counting Sort in $O(|E|)$. But can I say that this results in O(|E|+|V|)? Since Kruskal would normally be ${\displaystyle O(T_{sort}(|E|)+|E|\cdot \alpha (|V|))} =O(|E|)$ when $\alpha (|V|) \in O(1)$ Can this be stated for this case? I lack detailed understanding of inverse ackerman behaviour.
- Other possibility changing Prim so that I use a priority queue which support del_min, decreaseKey and insert in $O(1)$. I thought about using two simple stacks or queues and only del_min from the one, which holds the 1 integers, but descreaseKey seems not efficient since I have to loop through the lists to find the elements. So maybe combine this with some kind so hash mapping to directly access each element in $O(1)$ for decreaseKey?

Both seem really close to the actual result, though I am struggling to see the right solution for this case.

Comment: Similar to this question: [Find an MST in a graph with edge weights from {1,2}](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/28635/4287)

Comment: In the @HendrikJan 's link, I recommend looking at the second part of their answer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/28650/1149666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=|V|$ and $m=|E|$.

Intuitively you want the to return the union of the edges in 1) a maximal spanning forest $F$ of the graph induced by the edges of weight $1$, with 2) a maximal spanning forest $F'$ of the graph obtained by identifying the edges of each tree in $F$ into a single vertex (where each edge in $F'$ actually represents an edge of $G$).

Some care is required to attain a running time of $O(n)$. The details are as follows.

---

Let $G_1$ be subgraph of $G$ induced by the edges of weight $1$.
Let $C_1, \dots, C_k$ be the connected components of $G_1$.
For each $C_i$, compute any a spanning tree $T_i = (V_i, E_i)$ of $C_i$.
This requires $O(m)=O(n)$ time in total.

For each edge $e=(u,v)$ of weight $2$ in $G$ let $i$ and $j$ be such that $u \in C_i$ and $v \in C_j$. Let $k(e) = (\min\{i,j\}, \max\{i,j\})$.
Sort the edges of $G$ in nondecresing order of $k(\cdot)$, keep at most one edge for each value of $k(\cdot)$. Let $S$ the resulting ordered set of edges.
Notice that $S$ can be found in time $O(m)=O(n)$ using radix-sort.

Create a graph $G_2$ with vertex set $\{1, \dots, k\}$ and edge set $\{ k(e) : e \in S \}$. For an edge $(i,j)$ in $G_2$ let $\ell(i,j)$ be and edge $e$ in $G$ such that $k(e) = (i,j)$.
This *label* $\ell(i,j)$ can be stored along with the edge $(i,j)$ itself, so that given $(i,j)$ we can find $\ell(i,j)$ in $O(1)$ time.
This step also requires $O(n)$ time.

Finally, compute any spanning tree $T' = (V', E')$ of $G_2$.
An MST of $G$ is the tree induced by the edges in $\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^k E_i \right) \cup \{ \ell(i,j) \mid (i,j) \in E'\}$.

Overall, the whole algorithm takes $O(n)$ time.
The same algorithm extends naturally to any constant number of distinct edge weights.

Here is a visualization of the algorithm on the graph you proposed in the comments. Blue edges has weight $1$, red edges have weight $2$. The connected components of $G_1$ are highlighted in gray (and each connected component will be represented by a vertex in $G_2$). In this particular example $S$ contains all red edges of $G$ since each red edge connects a different (unordered) pair of connected components in $G_1$.

[image: example]

Comment: @JohnL. Sorry for not defining $n$ and $m$. I edited the answer. $m=\Theta(n)$ since, for $n>1$, the degree of each node is lower bounded by $1$ and upper bounded by $4$ (the input graph is a grid graph).

Comment: something I don´t understand about this procedure yet: given a $C_i, C_j$ so that we need at least two edges with the weight 2 to connect $C_i$ with $C_j$, it seems as if there wouldn´t be an edge within $k[]$ since it only holds edges which connect two different components with one edge or am I overlooking something? Another thing what is the label $\ell(i,j)$ used for? Is the step of computing the final MST something like looking at every edge and deciding whether it is in any $C_i$ or labeled with $\ell(i,j)$?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your comment, but why do you say that you need 2 edges of weight 2 to connect $C_i$ with $C_j$? Exactly one edge is needed (you cannot have more edges as otherwise you'd be creating a cycle). The label $\ell(i,j)$ is there just because, formally, $G_2$ is a completely different graph than $G$. $\ell(i,j)$ is telling you any edge of $G$ that can be used to connect $C_i$ and $C_j$. In the final step you just take all the edges in any $T_i$ (not $C_i$!) plus an arbitrary edge $e$ between $C_i$ and $C_j$ for each edge $(i,j)$ in $T'$. This edge $e$ is exactly $\ell(i,j)$.

Comment: Ok I will try to explain with the following example: given the Grid g 5x5 symbolized as matrix g[i][j] for the nodes within g and edges =([][],[][]) o,m,n,p ∈ [5], but only grid edges. What if the first row g[1] is only with costs of 1 and g[5] has only costs 1 again. g[k] with k = {2,3,4} would hold the costs of 2. Then I would have to use at least three edges to connect 1 (row 1) with 2 (row 5). Would  hold these edges as wel since there is no edge which satisfies k(e)=(min{1,2},max{1,2}) so that it connect 1 with 2

Comment: $k$ does not hold any edge, it is just a key used to get the sorted vector $S$ and to efficiently get rid of multiple edges between the same pair of components. $S$ contains edges. I think the misunderstanding here is that in your example graph $G_1$ contains 17 connected components. Namely, the whole first row, the whole last row, and one connected component for each vertex $g[i][j]$ with $i=2,3,4$ and $j=1,2,3,4,5$. Then $S$ contains all but $8$ edges of $G$. The $8$ missing edges are those in the first and last row. I've added a picture to my answer using your suggested graph as an example.

Comment: Thank you, this made it perfectly clear! Could this be applied to any weight constraint graph in efficient time?

Comment: Do you mean a graph in which edge weights are non-negative integers and are upper bounded by some constant $c$? If so, yes. The same approach gives you a $O(m+n)$-time algorithm. For each $i=0, \dots, c$, consider the graph that contains only edges of weight $i$ and in which all vertices in the same connected component of the graph induced by the edges of weight $<i$ are identified in single vertex. Let $E_i$ be the edges in any maximal (w.r.t. the number of edges) spanning forest of this graph. The MST of your input graph is induced by the edges in $\cup_i E_i$.